# can't get and pass variable uri segment to function for datatables server side

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, serverside-javascript

I'm using CodeIgniter and Datatable Server Side to show my data from database. I want to get segment url form my url view and pass that segment to my controller and show to last column in my table. But didn't work.

this my view url

```
http://localhost/sosboard/admin/module/55
```

this my controller

```
function data_module()
    {
        // Datatables Variables
        $submenu_id     = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
        $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
        $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

        $module= $this->m_admin->main_menu();
        $data = array();

        //$page = $data['write'];
        foreach ($module->result() as $rows) {
            $data[] = array(
                $rows->title,
                $rows->seq,
                $rows->target,
                $rows->icon_code,
                $rows->active,
                $submenu_id


            );
        }
        $output = array(
           "draw" => $draw,
             "recordsTotal" => $module->num_rows(),
             "recordsFiltered" => $module->num_rows(),
             "data" => $data
        );
      echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

this my html view & javascript

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <table class='table' id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Main Menu</th>
                    <th>Seq</th>
                    <th>Target</th>
                    <th>Icon Code</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/data_module/') ?>",
                "type": "GET"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

all column fine, but last column not shown.

Please help.
thanks

Comment: show datatable html code

Comment: see my update code @PankajMakwana

Comment: `'admin/data_module/'` third parameter is empty

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i mean i want get url current page. my current page is http://localhost/sosboard/admin/module/55, i want to get segment 3 (module).

Comment: @MardinoIsmail try segment 4

Comment: @AbdullaNilam oh sorry, i want to get segment 3 (module), it's not work. i have tried.

Comment: add complete question with all this URL access and form or what ever.

Comment: i think get the problem. i want to get segment from url my current page (localhost/sosboard/admin/module/55), but uri segment read url from my javascript function ( "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/data_module/') ?>"), can you help me with this @AbdullaNilam?

Comment: i didn't get your actual question

Comment: @AbdullaNilam see my update question. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165705/discussion-between-abdulla-nilam-and-mardino-ismail).

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are trying to get the segment from the uri `/admin/module/55` when you are *actually* on the page `/admin/data_module/` via ajax. Thus uri 3, and 4 don't exist as you expect them to. Only uri segments: (1) sosboard (2) admin (3) data_module exists in that page.

I would suggest passing the parameter as a get

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/data_module/') ?>",
                "type": "GET",
                'data': { param1: '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); // module ?>' }
            }
        });
    });
```

Data_module:

```
function data_module()
    {
        // Datatables Variables
        $submenu_id     = $this->input->get('param1');
```

If you need to get 55 from uri use segment 4. If you need to pass both then just add another parameter to ajax and get it the same way as I've shown.